# window.navigator.online not working in all browsers and its all versions. Need a generic solution

Tags: javascript

I need to check the connection availability  but,
`window.navigator.online` not working in all browsers and its all versions. Need a generic solution that works in all the browsers and its all versions. It is not working mostly in the Chrome and Safari and in latest version of the Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ajax call to test connectivity is the generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on that property.

You could request an image, and if it errors, assume the user is offline.